# NUnit 3.x - TestCaseSource for descendant test classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I currently have a set of unit tests which are consistent for a number of Rest API endpoints. Say the class is defined like so.

```
public abstract class GetAllRouteTests<TModel, TModule>
{
  [Test]
  public void HasModels_ReturnsPagedModel()
  {
     // Implemented test
  }
}
```

With the implemented test fixture looking like:

```
[TestFixture(Category = "/api/route-to-test")]
public GetAllTheThings : GetAllRouteTests<TheThing, ModuleTheThings> { }
```

This enables me to run a number of common tests across all GET all/list routes. It also means that I have classes which are linked directly to the module being tested, and links between tests and code in Resharper / Visual Studio / CI "just work".

The challenge is that some routes require query parameters for testing other pathways through the route code;

e.g. /api/route-to-test?category=big.

As [TestCaseSource] requires a static field, property, or method there appears to be no nice way to override a list of query strings to pass. The closest thing I have come up with seems like a hack. Namely:

```
public abstract class GetAllRouteTests<TModel, TModule>
{
  [TestCaseSource("StaticToDefineLater")]
  public void HasModels_ReturnsPagedModel(dynamic args)
  {
     // Implemented test
  }
}

[TestFixture(Category = "/api/route-to-test")]
public GetAllTheThings : GetAllRouteTests<TheThing, ModuleTheThings> 
{
    static IEnumerable<dynamic> StaticToDefineLater() 
    {
       // yield return all the query things
    }
}
```

This works because the static method is defined for the implemented test class, and is found by NUnit. Huge hack. Also problematic for someone else consuming the abstract class as they need to "know" to implement "StaticToDefineLater" as a static something.

I am looking for a better way of achieving this. It seems like non-static TestCaseSource sources were removed in NUnit 3.x, so that's out.

Thanks in advance.

NOTES:

- GetAllRouteTests<> implements a number of tests, not just the one shown.
- Iterating through all the routes in one test will "hide" what is covered, so would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 5):

The way I solved a similar problem is by having a base source class that implements IEnumerable (another acceptable source for NUnit), consider if this design suits your usecase:

```
// in the parent fixture...
public abstract class TestCases : IEnumerable
{
    protected abstract List<List<object>> Cases { get; }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Cases.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

// in tests
private class TestCasesForTestFoobar : TestCases
{
    protected override List<List<object>> Cases => /* sets of args */
}

[TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCasesForTestFoobar))]
public void TestFoobar(List<object> args)
{
    // implemented test
}
```

Comment: Just as we intended. :-) Also, having the data in a separate class as you do here is much cleaner than putting it into the test class.

Comment: oh, neat - doesn't get much better than the endorsement of the framework's lead dev :)

Comment: So is it required to define [TestCaseSource*] attribute on the implemented fixture? Is there a way to define it on the parent fixture so that the common test can be implemented in the base / parent fixture?

Comment: @Charlie is there a way to put `TestCaseSource` in the parent abstract fixture instead of having to spam it in each class that inherits it?

Comment: @Vedran The attribute obviously has to appear on each test. But the data itself may be in a base class, using a field, property or method that is accessible to the inheriting fixture. It may also be in an unrelated class, provided you specify the Type in the `TestCaseSourceAttribute` constructor.